# How to find all active sessions of gmail and facebook accounts?

Tags: iphone, facebook-graph-api, gmail

After some research I found out  a way to check all the active sessions of gmail and face book manually. Is there are APIs to get details of these accounts an sign them out?

Comment: didnt got any apis till now. :(

Comment: Most webapps will prevent attempts to hijack them (e.g. via an iframe) and trick the user into logging out, Facebook certainly does

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any APIs, but that doesn't mean you couldn't get the same functionality by screen-scraping the sites. Without an API, however, your code is subject to potential breakage whenever Facebook or Google update their web apps.

#### Facebook

For facebook, you could screen-scrape the URL `https://www.facebook.com/settings?tab=security&section=sessions&t`. Also investigate the URL `https://www.facebook.com/ajax/settings/security/sessions/stop.php?__a=1`, which is the URL accessed in the background when you click the "End Activity" link.

#### GMail

Google's seems to be a little more complex, but if you screen-scrape `https://mail.google.com/mail/h/` (the plain-html interface), find and follow the "Details" link at the bottom, you may be able to automatically log sessions out that way too.

Comment: I know these details infact this is what inpired to find some APIs can you share some details for APIs cause I have seen an app on appstore which can do this

Answer (score -1):

For Google I found another article that made this easy. [google account logout and redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4202161/google-account-logout-and-redirect)
As for Facebook they have the fb API you can get in JavaScript and php. These will allow you to control the currently logged in user account. There are log-out functions for the user as well. However digging around in the account is difficult to do because your domain can't see the data for that user without being authorized by both Facebook and the user.
Dig around here if you want to deal with facebook data and access. https://developers.facebook.com/ Open graph is fairly easy to use.

Comment: there is no API in graph API  for this I have already drilled that

Comment: If you are saying you can't get info about the user in the graph api then you didn't look hard enough. If you are talking about the log out thing, that's because its insecure to allow people to do so.
$.getJSON("https://graph.facebook.com/me?"+token+"callback=?",function(data){console.log(data)}); That would get information about the current user. However, you would need a token to do so. There is no way to just collect this information without permission.