# "https://www.google.com/accounts/Logout" clears all the google cookies in browser

Tags: asp.net, redirect, cookies, openid

I am trying to use Google as OpenID.
Users can successfully login to my site using their Google email.
**Problem:** They can't sign out successfully from it.

When user clicks sign out button in my website, i can only clear the cookies issued by my site itself but not the cookies  issued under Google.
I have googled as well as read many article in stackoverflow. The solution i found is that i can't delete Google cookies myself. In order to delete that cookie i have to redirect my Page to https://www.google.com/accounts/Logout which cleans the Cookies issued by Google in my browser.

**Another Problem begins:** That url clears all the google cookies in the browser.If the user is login in other sites using  Google as OpenID or even gmail at the same time in the same browser, their cookies also get deleted while logging out of my site.
Is there solution to it?

For Demo Try following steps in your own brower:
1- Login Gmail with your own authentication
2. then Click on https://www.google.com/accounts/Logout.
What will happen is your gmail account will be logout automatically.

Comment: What are you trying to log them out *from*?

Comment: I still don't get it. Are you trying to log them out of your site? Are you trying to log them out of Google? Or what?

Comment: I have to do both while using OpenID

Comment: Okay, so which are you having trouble with?

Comment: Sorry but again edited. This time hope you will get the thing i want to ask.

Comment: Nope, still don't get it. You want to log them out of your site, right? So why are you even trying to log them out of their Google account? If you're trying to log them out of their Google account, why are you complaining that it logs them out of their Google account?

Comment: @simplybj this link exactly solves ur problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4202161/google-account-logout-and-redirect

Answer (score 2):

As far as what I understand from your post, you want to log your users out of Google. For which you can use https://www.google.com/accounts/Logout without a problem.

You can use the following function to do it for you:

```
var logout = function()
{
    document.location.href = "https://www.google.com/accounts/Logout?continue=https://appengine.google.com/_ah/logout?continue=http://stackoverflow.com";
}
```

where you should replace `http://stackoverflow.com` with your home page.

This should help you get your job done.

Comment: What's up with the first "?continue=" there?

Comment: how to avoid redirect notice page, i want to redirect my website

Answer (score -1):

Here is a sign-out URL from all Google account, which is working fine for me:

https://accounts.google.com/Logout?continue=https%3A%2F%2Faccounts.google.com%2FServiceLogin%3Fsacu%3D1&il=true&zx=icxpgruz0yao

Hope it will help you.

Comment: He is looking for a way to log out of his site *without* logging out of all Google accounts.