# Global logout from lightopenid

Tags: php, lightopenid

I have made a openid login system using google, yahoo which is working fine, problem is when user logout from my site it doses not logout from google, yahoo. how to make a global logout which logout user from my site and also from google, yahoo.

a simple `session_destroy();` only logout from my site.

in order to logout from google and yahoo i need to trigger these url in background.

```
https://mail.google.com/?logout
http://login.yahoo.com/?logout=1
```

i can use some form submission method to take the user to these url but it will then show the respective google, yahoo logout page, i want to log them out and show them my site logout page.

Please see and suggest any way to do it.

Thanks.

Comment: There is an answer to this question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4202161/google-account-logout-and-redirect

Answer (score 1):

For my CMS that I wrote, I destroy the cookie first, then redirect the URL to **https://accounts.google.com/Logout**.