# About websites login & logout with Google SDK in php

Tags: google-api-php-client

why I press 'logout' it just logout my websites, But google account is still login state?

test sites below:
http://www.hyh.clhyc.tw/GoogleSDK/index.php

my php code:
http://www.hyh.clhyc.tw/GoogleSDK/phpCode.txt

Comment: That's how it works. Why should your website be able to log me out of a different one? If I want to log out of Google, I'll go there to do it.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (isset($_REQUEST['logout'])) {
  unset($_SESSION['token']);
  session_destroy();
  $gClient->revokeToken();
  header('Location: ' . filter_var($redirect_uri, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL)); //redirect user back to page
}
```

when logout is clicked the token get destroyed, it doesn't logout of google all the token does is it authorizes your app to interact with the users account [image]

once the token expired or revoked the user needs to reauthorize your app to interact with their account.

If you you want to logout of their google account you can [read here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14831349/4535386)

Comment: @Matt_HYH if it answerd your question please select as best answer, Thanks.