# Why did https://appengine.google.com/_ah/logout redirect stop working?

Tags: google-app-engine, logout

Up until yesterday afternoon users of our application could logout from Google via our application by pressing a "Log out"-button. The button would log the user out by directing the browser to "https://www.google.com/accounts/Logout?continue=https://appengine.google.com/_ah/logout?continue=https://www.example.com". Google would redirect the browser to https://appengine.google.com/_ah/logout which in turn would take the user back to the application https://www.example.com.

Now the user instead gets redirected to "https://www.google.com/url?sa=D&q=https://www.example.com" in which the user must click a link to get to the application.

Why did this change?

[We use the answer from this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4202161/google-account-logout-and-redirect)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I tried the log out-button again after the weekend and it now works like before. The only explanation I can see is that Google somehow fixed their services somewhere.

Comment: I'm using the same approach but still getting redirect notice, did you figure out how to solve that?

Comment: This is not working any more. It is intended behavior, [please check this case for answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54346026/https-appengine-google-com-ah-logout-still-working/55853066#55853066)