# https://appengine.google.com/_ah/logout still working?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-oauth, logout, openid-connect, angular-oauth2-oidc

Until a few days ago I could use the log out from google account procedure mentioned (among several others) in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4202161/google-account-logout-and-redirect).

The recommended log out URL is similar to: 
https://www.google.com/accounts/Logout?continue=https://appengine.google.com/_ah/logout?continue=http://localhost:4200/index.html

But all of a sudden when navigating to the recommended URL, a redirection notice page appears instead of navigating directly to  http://localhost:4200/index.html

In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53116671/why-did-https-appengine-google-com-ah-logout-redirect-stop-working) previous question a similar problem was reported, but also that the problem solved itself shortly after

Can anyone confirm that the log out from google account URL is still working?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

> Redirection notice page appearance is the [intended behavior](https://issuetracker.google.com/123494117) of the appengine API.

For security reasons it will no longer work, unless [URL will be signed](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signed-urls#overview).

Please check documentation, [how to sign URL with the appengine API](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signed-urls#signing-gcp).

---

Example: you can find documentation and test it on the [API method page](https://cloud.google.com/iam/credentials/reference/rest/v1/projects.serviceAccounts/signBlob). Expanding `try this API` window, you will get access to example in curl, http and javascript.

You also need to use `?key=<YOUR_API_KEY>` part with the [secret key for authentication](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/api-keys)

```
curl --request POST \
  'https://iamcredentials.googleapis.com/v1/projects/-/serviceAccounts/<service-account-name>%40<project-name>.iam.gserviceaccount.com:signBlob?key=<YOUR_API_KEY>' \
  --header 'Authorization: Bearer <YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN>' \
  --header 'Accept: application/json' \
  --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  --data '{"payload":"<BLOB-TO-SIGN>"}' \
  --compressed
```

Comment: The documentation does not explain how to use a signed URL with the endpoint `https://appengine.google.com/_ah/logout?continue=xxxx`. Could you add an example here?

Comment: @Pawel Czuczwara So what is the logout url for web now? What do we need to add in this url "https://www.google.com/accounts/Logout?continue=https://appengine.google.com/_ah/logout?continue=" ?

Comment: URL has to be signed. Please check documentation for this: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signed-urls

Comment: Can it be any URL? The link you provided seems to only work with gs:// urls (i.e., redirecting to Google Cloud resources).